# How to change parent to that of a child's text in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an html page with several occurrences of descriptions that are not hyperlinked, accompanied by an explicit hyperlink, like so:

```
<h2 class="description">Awesome website!</h2>
<p><a href="http://www.google.com/">http://www.google.com/</a></p>
```

When the screen gets below a certain size, I want (1) the explicit link to go away and (2) the description to become hyperlinked. As an intermediate step, I just want to change the `h2` to have the text of the `a`, but this isn't working:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 500) {
        $(".description").text($(this).siblings("p").find("a").text());
        $("a").hide();
    } else {
        $("a").show();
        // replace the description, too
    }
});
```

I tried to dial in a little more, and found that this doesn't even work:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if($(window).width() < 500) {
        $(".description").text($(this).text()); // the description disappears
    }
});
```

even though `console.log($(".description").text());` gives me the text associated with the `description`.

I'm guessing that the text I want to use is going out of existence before it can be used.

Is there a workaround or a correct way to do this? I know I could hyperlink both and remove / reinstate the hyperlink as the screen size changes, but I wonder if something like what I'm trying can work.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using media queries?

Comment: I think you have a misconception about `this`

Comment: Nothing besides ignorance, I guess -- I'm not as familiar with the more complicated features of CSS. I didn't realize you could actually replace text with a media query.

Comment: @itamar, I figured out how to do this with media queries using display: hidden. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(window).width() < 500) {
            // Traverse all .description
            $(".decription").each(function(){

                // Fetch the next a tag inside the next p
                $el_a = $(this).next("p").find("a")[0];

                // Fetch it's href and hide it
                var href = $el_a.href;
                $el_a.hide();

                // Build new html for description by wrapping it in <a></a> with previous href.
                $(this).html(function(){
                  return '<a href="'+$el_a.html()+'">'+this.innerHTML+'</a>';
                });
            });
        } else {
            $(".decription").each(function(){

                // Fetch the next a tag inside the next p
                $el_a = $(this).next("p").find("a")[0];

                // Show this element
                $el_a.show();

                // Modify the html by setting its html as the html of its children a
                $(this).html(function(){
                  return $(this).children("a").html();
                });
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var $el = $(".description"),
    $sib = $el.siblings('p'),
    desc = $el.text(), // h2 text
    rdesc = $sib.text(); // a text

console.log(desc, rdesc)

$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 500) {
    $(".description").text(rdesc); // replace h2 text if < 500
    $sib.hide() // hide p
  } else {
    $(".description").text(desc); // replace h2 text if != < 500
    $sib.show() // show p
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="description">Awesome website!</h2>
<p><a href="http://www.google.com/">Google Link</a>
</p>
```

check this Fiddle with resizing :- https://jsfiddle.net/toopbbLr/